# NFC service dead android.os.DeadObjectException

Tags: android, nfc, android-networking

We are working on NFC tag android app and it is working properly 50% of times, and rest of the times we get NFC service dead exception in below try blocks:

Scenario is we connect to nfc Tag first time and send data, it always works fine.
Then we **don't move** phone away and after 1-2 seconds we again tries to connect to nfc tag(if not connected) to send data and 30% of times we get NFC service dead exception and it doesn't start until we disable and enable mobile's NFC.

```
Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY 
                          + Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);                 //first line of doInBackground()
        if(((ArrayList<Byte>) params[0]).size()<=0){
            return "No image selected!";
        }
        NfcA nfcaTag = (NfcA) params[2];
        try{
                    nfcaTag = NfcA.get(tag);
                    if (!nfcaTag.isConnected()){
                        nfcaTag.connect();        //this is line 175 MainActivity
                    }

        try {
                    nfcaTag.close();
                }
```

Exception:

```
NFC service dead
                                                              android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:622)
                                                                  at android.nfc.INfcTag$Stub$Proxy.connect(INfcTag.java:285)
                                                                  at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.connect(BasicTagTechnology.java:73)
                                                                  at android.nfc.tech.NfcA.connect(NfcA.java)
                                                                  at de.silab.nfc.vistagnfcappv1.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:175)
                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5723)
                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22689)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Is there any way to solve this issue. We are stuck here since long time.
And any way to restart NFCAdapter/ nfc service by catching this exception?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue at the end?

Comment: Yes, if you handle nfcaTag instance properly this issue doesn't occur.

Comment: @chinmay_92 How do you handle instance properly?

Comment: check the accepted answer, you need to close the instance of nfcaTag properly in order to avoid service exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nfcaTag's hosting process is dead. It has been `close()`'d. Your first step should be to debug by logging info to the console about your variables to see if something is unusual.

I find it strange that you `close()` your `nfcaTag` immediately after `connect()`'ing it. Maybe these two statements conflict?

Also, consider why you have initialized the `nfcaTag` only to change it immediately in the next try statement.

Is your `NfcA.get(tag)` occasionally returning a null `NfcA` object? Is `tag` occasionally null? You need to test every variable, especially the ones you haven't shared here completely in your question.

Comment: Sorry for confusion,there is sending method in between two try blocks